# Select attachments using Exchange Web Services

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, email-attachments

Sorry if my post is a duplicate one, I tried to find a solution without success.
I need to read an Office365 email folder and get the attachments contained in each mail.
I use this code

```
foreach (Attachment attachment in message.Attachments)
{
    if (attachment is FileAttachment)
    {
        FileAttachment fileAttachment = attachment as FileAttachment;
        // Load the attachment into a file.
        // This call results in a GetAttachment call to EWS.
        fileAttachment.Load("C:\\temp\\" + fileAttachment.Name);

        Console.WriteLine("File attachment name: " + fileAttachment.Name);
    }
    else // Attachment is an item attachment.
    {
        ItemAttachment itemAttachment = attachment as ItemAttachment;
        // Load attachment into memory and write out the subject.
        // This does not save the file like it does with a file attachment.
        // This call results in a GetAttachment call to EWS.
        itemAttachment.Load();
        Console.WriteLine("Item attachment name: " + itemAttachment.Name);
    }
}
```

taken from here [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-get-attachments-by-using-ews-in-exchange) to do this.
But together the "real" attachments sent by the sender (pdf files, xls, or images too) the code downloads all the elements contained in each mail, i.e. logos, images inside the html body, etc.
There is a way to select only the "real" attachments and to avoid downloading logos, and other html elements contained inside the body?
Thanks for your help.
Lucius

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to filter based on the other property on the Fileattachment class https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.fileattachment?view=exchange-ews-api

eg

```
if(!Attachment.IsInline)
```

or check the if the ContentId is null etc

Comment: Your solution is perfect. Thanks a lot!